# How to integrate Azure B2C with Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, azure-ad-b2c

How do I use Azure B2C with Entity Framework, or any other back-end system?

The documentation for Azure B2C does not seem to discuss integration with back-end systems, and I'm at a loss as to how this is achieved.

I do not need the user to authenticate against the database, but I want to store user-specific data in the database. This could entail the use of a **Users** table, for example.

Comment: How do you envision an integration of Customer Authentication with an ORM? Normally new users can register at any time, which means integrating it with EF doesn't make sense.

Comment: @rickvdbosch I'd like my users to be able to store data in a database.

Comment: Your application should have access to the database, you _do not_ want database authentication to be connected to customer authentication. In short: your _application_ has access to the database, and might store user specific information in that database.

Comment: I don't want users to authenticate against the database. I would like to know how to store user-specific information in the database. How can the database know about newly created users?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Active Directory B2C authentication and making/storing user IDs in a DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40062902/active-directory-b2c-authentication-and-making-storing-user-ids-in-a-db)

Comment: That explains the principles of Azure AD tokens, but what's the actual mechanism? How does my app know about new users, for example?

Answer (score 0):

The design of the DB is up to you.

The normal way is to add the DB primary key of the user as an extension attribute for the user in B2C.

When the user logs in, get the [extension attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-custom-attributes?pivots=b2c-custom-policy) and pass it to an [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/restful-technical-profile) that handles all the DB activity.

Comment: But what is the mechanism for the app to be made aware of the newly created user? How do I intercept this callback from the B2C login process?

Answer (score 0):

See MS documentation [Use API connectors to customize and extend sign-up user flows and custom policies with external identity data sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory-b2c/api-connectors-overview?pivots=b2c-custom-policy/)

> you can verify that the email address provided by the user exists in
> your customer's database, and if not, present an error.
>
> Your RESTful service can receive the user's email address, query the
> customer's database, and return the user's loyalty number to Azure AD
> B2C

You can use an example
[A B2C IEF Custom Policy which authenticates to AAD and calls a REST API for more claims](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/AAD-SignIn-with-REST)